# How to get sources in my project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get sources added to my project.  I manually added the below repo and included an atmosphere snapshot.

```xml
<repositories>
    <!-- Added to get the Atmosphere 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, can be removed when 1.1.0 is released -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I went and downloaded the `.jar` from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/) but when I add it to the "libraries" section in my Project Structure it doesn't add it as a source, but adds it under Classes.

In debugging when viewing the interface of a class, I've used the quick "Attach sources..." option at the top of the editor and navigated to the .jar with no avail.

Comment: Maven Projects tool window has a button to download sources and documentation.

Comment: The automated downloader doesn't find the sources.  I'm not sure why, but it fails.  So I'm trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven doesn't find the sources, because there are no sources of that library in that Maven repository (which i think is quite common for snapshots of a library). I downloaded one of the jars, and they contain only class files, so i'm wondering, how you can see the sources even if you attach the jar manually.

Comment: I haven't been able to view the sources, which is why I was confused.  Thank you for confirming there aren't any sources available.

Comment: Maven expects sources to be in a jar with the following naming scheme: artifactid-version-sources.jar, e.g. atmosphere-runtime-1.0.12-sources.jar. Usually they are only created when releasing a maven artifact. As you can see, the release artifacts in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/1.0.12/ contain source jars, snapshots doesn't.